# SQL grouping issue

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Neea a help with grouping in sql.

I've table like

```
id1 id2 type
1   1   300
1   3   300
1   2   300
1   5   300
2   2   100
2   5   200
2   7   300
4   3   100
4   9   300
4   2   300
```

I need id1 that is mapped to one type only,

 For eg, id1 '1' is mapped only to type 300, so it should only be retrieved 
If there is more than one type mapped to an id1 it shouldnt be retrieved. Please help.
Here is what I have attempted. But it will handle only for type 300.
I need to retrieve all the id1's which are mapped to one particular type alone. So if id1 '2' is mapped for type '100' alone, it should also be retrieved.

```
SELECT distinct id1 from ID_TABLE where type = 300 and id1 not in 
 (SELECT id1 from type_table where type in (100, 200, 250)) 
 and id1 in ( SELECT id1 FROM ID_TABLE type=300) 
 order by id1
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: Could you update your question and add expected results? Also, as already pointed out, please show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e7ac/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( id1, id2, type ) AS
          SELECT 1,   1,   300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,   3,   300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,   2,   300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,   5,   300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   2,   100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   5,   200 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   7,   300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,   3,   100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,   9,   300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,   2,   300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,   4,   200 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,   2,   200 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,   4,   200 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT   id1,
         MIN( type )
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY id1
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT type ) = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e7ac/2/0)**:

```
| ID1 | MIN(TYPE) |
|-----|-----------|
|   1 |       300 |
|   5 |       200 |
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `group by` below you may still have multiple `id1` so `having` will limit to only those situations when there is a single id1 for type. Using `MIN` as an arbitrary aggregator here as there is only one value anyway:

```
SELECT MIN(id1), type
FROM type_table
  GROUP BY type
HAVING COUNT(id1)=1;
```